# How can i put an option value in a input text after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, button, input

I'm not familiar with javascript and jQuery and I'm asking you.
I would like the code of a product to be selected, once I have selected it from the `select` dropdown, I click the button and it should add the value in an input box text, that I have created, so that I can also accumulate more codes of more products.
Keep in mind that once the button is clicked, the same value is no longer added indefinitely but that it is possible to choose another code and add it next to the one already present in the input text.

I don't know if it is more practical to use the `<input type = "submit">` tag instead of the `button` tag to send or in this case transfer the selected text from the `select` to a text form.

You would save my life if you could please complete this action for me with javascript or jQuery :)

```html
<select class="select" id="select-code">
    <option value="">Select a code</option>
    <option value="value1">Code 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Code 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Code 3</option>
    <option value="value4">Code 4</option>
</select>
<button id="code-btn">submit to form</button>
<input name="my-quote" type="text" placeholder="code1,code2...">
```

Comment: I recommend you research a "pills" plugin and use that.  Here's one to get you started: https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox

Comment: i didn't think there was this external resource, which is less demanding than writing some JS / jQ code for me still at the abc. I am using wordpress and found it as a plug-in compatible with contact form 7. For now I will use it as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems that you are complete beginner. so you should learn DOM api to learn how to manipulate the window.

Anyway here is the code to do so which you want;

```js
document.getElementById('code-btn').onclick = () => {
let e = document.getElementById('select-code');
document.getElementById('input').value =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<select class="select" id="select-code">
    <option value="">Select a code</option>
    <option value="value1">Code 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Code 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Code 3</option>
    <option value="value4">Code 4</option>
</select>
<button id="code-btn">submit to form</button>
<input id='input' name="my-quote" type="text" placeholder="code1,code2...">
```

`document.getElementById('code-btn')` gets the element with id '`code-btn`'. As that is a button, we can use `onclick` property which will will take a function and that function will be called when it is clicked.

Inside that function, i am simply getting the input field and setting its value to the text of the selected option from dropdown.

I think the code here is self-documented.

Comment: hello, you approached it too, thanks for your time, as already said in the other comments, I would not be able to modify your JS code for what I would like to do simply because I lack the basics and I have to find the time to learn it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but an alternative solution. If possible for your situation, I would consider using `<select multiple>`: the select tag with the "multiple" attribute. It's a native HTML feature that allows the user to select multiple options from the list. I don't know how you're submitting the form data, but if using a `<form>` tag then the form's data will include which values have been selected.

[Tutorial about select multiple](https://html.com/attributes/select-multiple/)

```html
<label for="select-code">Select a code</label>
<select class="select" id="select-code" multiple>
    <option value="value1">Code 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Code 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Code 3</option>
    <option value="value4">Code 4</option>
</select>
<button id="code-btn">submit to form</button>
<input id='input' name="my-quote" type="text" placeholder="code1,code2...">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very simple and might be used as beginers excercise, so I'm gonna give you a brief walkthrough of how I would solve it:

1. register button onClick event
2. read selected value
3. add it to the placeholder attribute

so something like this (not tested at all)

```
//button click event
$("#code-btn").click(function (event) {
                //in element #select-code
var textToAdd = $('#select-code')
    //find element with pseudo selector :selected
    .find(":selected")
        //get its inner text
        .text();

//check if input already contains the text here, if not
if (!$("input").attr("placeholder").includes(textToAdd)) {

    //into input element
    $("input")
        //into attribute placehoder
        .attr("placeholder",
            //insert original text         //insert colon     //insert new text
            $("input").attr("placeholder") + ", " +           textToAdd)
    }
});
```

Comment: If they're a complete beginner and it's "very simple", then you should probably provide them with a working snippet rather than some untested "something like this" which they'll have difficulty debugging if it doesn't work 100%

Comment: exactly, since I'm a n00b :) in this field I will use the solution proposed by @dan

Comment: I though you werent supposed to do anyones homework here, but rather to point struggling learners/students in direction aiming towards achiving their goal. I beg my pardon for not unit-testing code I thought off-hand...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {

  var newText = document.getElementById('select-code').value
  var input = document.getElementById('my-quote')

  if (input.value == '') input.value = newText
  else input.value = input.value + ', ' + newText
  
}
```

```html
<select class="select" id="select-code" onchange='myFunction()'>
  <option value="">Select a code</option>
  <option value="Code 1">Code 1</option>
  <option value="Code 2">Code 2</option>
  <option value="Code 3">Code 3</option>
  <option value="Code 4">Code 4</option>
</select>
<button id="code-btn">submit to form</button>
<input id="my-quote" type="text" placeholder="code1,code2...">
```

Comment: hi, i looked at your code and thank you for answering and for your time, you came pretty close but once you hit the button it should do exactly what your code does. I tried to add onclick = "myFunction ()" to the button but it returns "Cannot read property 'value' of null" ". From the select I promptly removed it. Could you tell me why it gives me that error?

Comment: did you add the id my-quote to the input tag?  If this works for you please accept answer, if not, provide more information as to what you want to do